# Is the effective access time calculation incorrect

Tags: operating-system

In galvin’s book *Operating System Concepts 9th Edition (International Student Version)*, the Effective Access Time is described as

**effective access time = (1 − p) × ma + p × page fault time** ,where **ma** stands for the memory access time and the page fault rate is denoted by **p**.

According to this book, the **page fault time** doesn’t take **ma** into account.

But when the system has found a page fault, it should have had visited the page table. In this case, I think, the page fault handling cost should be **ma+ page fault time**. Then effective access time can be described as **(1 − p) × ma + p × (ma+page fault time)=ma+p × page fault time**.